# Zeppelin notebooks on HDInsight with Enterprise Security Package

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, shiro, apache-zeppelin, azure-hdinsight

I set up an HDInsight Spark cluster with the Enterprise Security Package (for multi-user access via Active Directory). Via the Azure portal, I used the link to go to a Zeppelin notebook (to run Spark SQL queries). This brings me to a login page for the notebook. Unfortunately, it's not clear what usernames/passwords are to be used. Neither local Ambari users nor synced AD users seem to work.

From some web searching, I gather that Zeppelin uses Apache Shiro to implement access control. However, I haven't found documentation as to which existing usernames/passwords to use or how to create new usernames/passwords.

Has anyone found a way to run Zeppelin notebooks on HDInsight with ESP? Thanks for any lifelines.

ETA: I was able to add a Zeppelin user by logging into the HDInsight head node (ssh) and editing /etc/zeppelin/conf/shiro.ini. This file also shows the AD setup that ESP produced.

To add an admin user, add a section as below, as per Apache Shiro documentation:

```
[users]
myuser mypassword, admin
```

These credentials should now be usable for logging into the Zeppelin portal. I also restarted the Zeppelin daemon, but don't know if it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use your domain credentials in order to log in to Zeppelin. If you are still facing issues, please open a support case and we will look into this.

Comment: Would these be the synced AD users? I have tried, but with no luck. Is there any way to get a list of the users who have access (e.g., maybe somewhere on the HDInsight head node, where I can log in with SSH)? Any particular format to the credentials (e.g., DOMAIN\username, just username, username@full.domain.path.com, etc.)?